# TikZ: constructing a piece of a hyperbola with a given asymptote

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[convert = false, border = 1cm, tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) circle[radius = .35cm];
  \draw (-60:1.5cm) -- +(0, 4);
  \draw (0, 0) -- (-60:1.5cm);
  \filldraw[black] (-60:.35cm) circle[radius = .04cm] node[below, font =
  \scriptsize] {P};
  \draw (-60:1.5cm) -- ++(150:4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I construct a hyperbola that has the given asymptotes and goes through point `P`?

What we know is that the turn angle is `120` degrees, the distance from `P` to the intersection of the lines is `1.5cm` which is the semi-major axis, and the radius at periapsis is `.35cm`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it easier to draw and then rotate everything by the appropriate angle.

**Edit**: If you want the origin of the coordinate system to coincide with the centre of the circle, simply translate the `scope` as shown in my code below (the `shift` is applied before the `rotate`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\angle{60}
    \def\circradius{.35}
    \def\a{1.5}
    \def\asymlen{4}
        \begin{scope}[rotate={\angle/2},shift={(0,{-\a-\circradius})}]
        \draw (0,0) -- (0, {\a+\circradius}) circle[radius = \circradius];
        \draw ({90-\angle/2}:0) -- ({90-\angle/2}:\asymlen);
        \draw ({90+\angle/2}:0) -- ({90+\angle/2}:\asymlen);
        \filldraw[black] (0,\a)
            circle[radius = .04cm] node[right, font =\scriptsize] {P};
        \def\myangle{60}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\b{\a/tan(\myangle)}
        \draw plot[domain=-2:2,samples=100] ({\x},{\a*sqrt(1+(\x/\b)^2)});
    \end{scope}
    \fill[red] (0,0) circle[radius = .1cm]; % CS origin
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```